# How do I create single cell arrays based on unique contiguous groups?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A identifies unique families using multiple other columns of data.
Column B is a list of individuals.

I would like Column C to contain cell arrays of these families (Shown Below).
For some reason, the MATCH formula in my attempted solution is returning the last occurrence of the match, so it does not work.

I have tried this formula (the output of this is shown in Column D in the picture):

`{=OFFSET(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(A1,A:A)),0,1,COUNTIF(A:A,A1))}`

```
A   B       C                               D
1   Tom 1   {Tom One, Sue One}              Sue 1
1   Sue 1   {Tom One, Sue One}              Sue 1
2   Bob 2   {Bob Two, Joan Two, John Two}   John 2
2   Joan 2  {Bob Two, Joan Two, John Two}   John 2
2   John 2  {Bob Two, Joan Two, John Two}   John 2
3   Tom 3   {Tom Three}                     Tom 3
4   Joe 4   {Joe Four}                      Joe 4
```

Comment: It would be good if you could include Excel Version you are using as some formula features such as `TEXTJOIN` are version specific.

Comment: If you want your `MATCH` formula to return the first entry, then set the optional `match_type` argument to `0`

Comment: What does your realistic data and desired output look like?  It may be a simple Power Query can be appropriate.  Otherwise you've got to create a spellnumber type function in excel formulas, which is not simple.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I think adding the    match_type    argument should do it. I will have to go back and add this.

Comment: Adding the match type was perfect. Silly mistake ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am not at all familiar with power queries, but I like learning. If it would work, let me know. What I’m doing is this: I have a master list of all participants in an insurance plan and their families. This report always list families together (participant first and then family members). I am identifying which families are eligible for Medicare based on certain criteria (employee status, ages, etc.) I was creating arrays to index each family for INDEX-MATCH lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula, the condition is that it is sorted baed on column A:

```
="{"&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A1,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A1,A:A,1)))&"}"
```